# Ionic 2 - Loading Controller doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use the recently added LoadingController this way :

```
let loading=this.load.create({
  content: "Connexion au serveur Migal en cours..."
});

loading.present();

this.http.get(this.urlCheckerForm.value.migalUrl+'/action/MobileApp/URLChecker')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => this.newConnection(data,loading),
    error => this.catchURLError(loading));

loading.dismiss();
```

Basically, I just want to display my loading pop-in before my page is loaded, and dismiss it after.

I followed the example on [Ionic 2 Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/), but it doesn't seem to work at all...

**EDIT :** The loading component doesn't even show up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're making the http request and then calling the `dismiss()` but the `dismiss()` method does not wait for the http request to finish. Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUjplv?p=preview).

The code is pretty much self-explanatory:

```
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  private users : Array<any>

  constructor(private http: Http, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    // Create the popup
    let loadingPopup = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Loading data...'
    });

    // Show the popup
    loadingPopup.present();

    // Get the data
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {

          // I've added this timeout just to show the loading popup more time
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.users= data;
            loadingPopup.dismiss();
          }, 1000);

          // Should be just this:
          // this.users= data;
          // loadingPopup.dismiss();
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm ! :) Thanks for your explanation. I forgot about the asymetric things.

Comment: after loadingPopup.dismiss();
you can't use it anymore. let us say we have a button and you want to show the loadingpopup whenever the user clicks on it, then you need to recreate the loadingpopup.

Answer (score 1):

I put "loading.dismiss();" in subscribe {} and it works well :)

```
                    this.http.get(url)
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                            this.items=JSON.parse(data['_body']).results;
                            loading.dismiss();
                        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ionic ionViewLoaded() to pop up the Loading Controller and then Dismiss it when the View is loaded and the Content Fetched from your Subscribtion.

```
ionViewLoaded() {
  let lr = this.loading.create({
    content: 'Your Display Message...',
  });

  lr.present().then(() => {
    this.Yourservice.Yourfunction()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.yourresult = res;
      });
    lr.dismiss();
  });
}
```

You can also structure your code like this to make sure the Subscription is Complete before you Dismiss the Loader.

```
ionViewLoaded() {
      let lr = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Your Display Message...',
      });

      lr.present().then(() => {
        this.Yourservice.Yourfunction()
          .subscribe(
          data => this.yourresult = data,
          error => console.log(error),
          ()=> lr.dismiss()
          );

      });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For the last versione of ionic you ve to handle the dismiss event:

```
let loading = this.load.create({
    content: "Connexion au serveur Migal en cours..."
});

loading.present();

loading.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
     do thinks..... 
});
```

Comment: Well, thanks to you, the loading component appear but keeps running forever :D

Comment: `loading.present();
   /* some stuff */
   loading.onDidDismiss(()=>{loading.dismiss();});`

Comment: I tried this but as I said, the spin keeps turning forever

Comment: no wait, you ve to make the http call inside the onDidDismiss event