# When to dismiss the ionic loading controller while waiting for an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

I'm wondering how to properly use the ionic-2 loading controller while waiting for async observable to arrive - as observable might arrive in none, single or many "waves" of responses.

**first question - how to present**

Should i use `loader.present()` or `loader.present().then(..`. i saw a lot of code examples that "ignore" the async nature of the loader (i even saw `loader.present(//function to execute)`

**second question - when to dismiss**

As mentioned, a response from a subscription can arrive in unknown "waves" of responses - taking it into account, when should i dismiss the loader? what if no response arrives? what if there are couple of responses? 
for example:

```
let loader = this.loadingController.create({content : "something"})
loader.present().then(()=>{
    source.subscribe((school)=>{
        this.schools.push(school)
        loader.dismiss()
        }, err=> loader.dismiss()
    )
 })
```

**third question - how to dismiss**

I noticed that there are a lot of issues regard the dismissing of the loading controller (e.g. [Ionic 2 - Loading Controller doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082539/ionic-2-loading-controller-doesnt-work)). Is catch after the dismiss is enough..? What to do if after the loading i want to push to another page...?

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> first question - how to present?

The correct way to present the loader is by using `then`, because otherwise you can face some issues related to buggy animations and maybe some other weird issues as well. After all, if the method returns a promise, the correct way to use it will always be to do something else when the promise is done.

```
loader.present().then(() => { /* ... */ });
```

I also do the same when I need to dismiss the loading:

```
loading.dismiss().then(() => { /* ... */ });
```

> second question - when to dismiss?

The idea if using a loading is to let the user know that something is happening in the background, so I think you should dismiss the loading after the *first wave*.

If no response arrives (so the results are empty for instance) you can include an `*ngIf="result.items.length === 0"` condition to show a div with a message saying that the results are empty. If a new *wave* arrives with some items in the result, that div will be hidden automatically.

> third question - how to dismiss?

Just like the `present` method, the `dismiss` also returns a promise. In this case, it's easier to see some buggy behavior in the animations if you don't use the `then`. So again, by just waiting to the dismiss method to end (by using the `then`) you can push a new page or do what you need to do and it should work properly:

```
loading.dismiss().then(() => { this.navCtrl.push(NewPage); });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! only question left for me is - if i'm dismissing it after "first wave", wouldn't it cause error to dismiss it "again" after the second wave?

Comment: another small issue - what about loading.dismiss() vs loading.onDismiss()...? I just had so much back and forth around this issue, i want to make sure i'm doing it right (once and for all) thank you!

Comment: Nothing will happen if you try to dismiss the loader several times since that is being handled internally by Ionic (please check [this demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BGyNrSvJYoFxX3J7rCbi?p=preview)). Regarding the `loading.onDismiss()` method, I don't use it often with loadingCtrl, but I've used it a lot with ModalCtrl to send information to the caller. I guess the best approach would be to use the `dismiss` method when you want to hide the loading alert, and also use the `loading.onDismiss()...` to handle things like android's physical button and some other strange scenarios.

Comment: Please also notice that `loading.dismiss() ` will dismiss the loading, while `loading.onDismiss()...` will be executed when the alert is dismissed, but it won't dismiss it by itself.